# After modifying Flask response functionality to support Pydantic, how can I prevent Pylance from complaining about the return type?

Tags: flask

I wanted to support returning a Pydantic model (`BaseModel`) from a flask route function, and although it seems to work I am facing a typing issue with Pylance and I'd like to fix it.

For a quick sumamry of what I've actually done, I've subclassed the Flask object like this:

```py
from flask import Flask, Response
from pydantic import BaseModel


class FlaskApplication(Flask):
    def make_response(self, rv):
        # If a pydantic model was returned, converts it to a dict
        if isinstance(rv, BaseModel):
            # Turn rv into a tuple with the status from the model (or None to default)
            rv = rv.model_dump(), getattr(rv, "status", None)
        elif isinstance(rv, tuple) and isinstance(rv[0], BaseModel):
            model = rv[0].model_dump()
            if not isinstance(rv[1], (str, int)) and len(rv) == 2:
                # This accounts for when the 1st index is a headers dict
                rv = (model, model.get("status"), rv[1])
            rv = (model, *rv[1:])
        return super().make_response(rv)

app = FlaskApplication(__name__)

...
```

It looks a bit convoluted (open to suggestions for improving that) so I'll give a quick explanation (skippable): This is just accounting for the fact that flask lets you return either a single object or a tuple of objects from a route, and that the HTTP status code could be at index 1 if that object is a string or int, otherwise index 1 will be a headers dict. Also, since I standardise my response schema (not shown), it contains the status code as a field `'status'`, so I wanted to default to using the status code specified in my schema, but to prefer the status explicitly returned in the tuple if there is one (e.g. prefer status 201 if for some reason we return `(MySchema(status=200), 201)`.

Anyway, assume I have a simple schema:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Simple(BaseModel):
    id: int
```

and assume I have some route like this:

```py
@app.get("/")
def simple_route():
    return Simple(id=0)
```

That works great and I get the expected result:

```json
{
    "id": 0
}
```

But Pylance is now complaining about my route function:

[image]

Clearly, the routing functionality does not support a `BaseModel` as a return value in its type hinting, so I guess this is causing Pylance to see that and flag it. It's not preventing the code from working but I want to correct this.

My thinking is that I should just need to override the routing functionality and provide a union of the official return type with my customised return type. But I am not sure and could use some help finding out how to resolve this.